# Display information on paypal

Tags: c#, paypal

[image: in below]

In the above image you can see a product name, price and sum of price as an 'Item Total'. I want to also display 'vat amount' and 'Total Amount' after 'Item Amount'.

I'm sending data to Paypal like this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='" + ProductName + "' name='item_name_'>
<input type='hidden' value='" + PriceExVat + "' name='amount_'>
```

Now I'm trying send the vat amount as:

```
<input type='hidden' value='" + VatAmount + "' name='vat_'>
```

But it is not displayed on Paypal. How can I display this?

Comment: You should probably contact whoever created this Paypal API

Comment: try changing the name of your input to tax rather that vat_

Comment: .. and see here for more information https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_cart_overrides_outside

Comment: @alexjamesbrown i have already used tax but not helpful

Comment: @Prashant16 sorry, try tax_cart

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do what you want to do with PayPal. One recommendation I can make is calculating the VAT on your end and passing it as a separate line item, or simply adding the VAT to the cost of each item itself.